# SQL Server: SELECT TOP 1001 to 1100 Rows

Tags: sql-server

Here is my prob,

I wanted to select particular 100 rows from a table that contains 70,000 rows. I tried with **OFFSET**, but it takes almost time taken for fetching all 70,000 rows.

I used this query,

```
select ContentUrl from EDContentMaster order by title desc 
offset 1000 rows 
fetch next 100 rows only
```

So is there any way to select particular 100 rows(*i.e from 1001th row to 1100th row*) with less time?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: use row number and based on that you can do this

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV:  can u plz explain bit more?

Comment: @RaJeshRiJo what is the execution plan ? How much time are we talking about? *Do* you have an index on `title` or does the server have to sort everything? 70K rows isn't a big number, even with no indexes you shouldn't be noticing a significant delay. Is this the entire query or is it part of a larger query?

Comment: @RaJeshRiJo based on what you want to fetch 100 rows?
are you using paging, will you pass any parameter?

Comment: I think @PanagiotisKanavos has right. There is a missing index on title. Check the execution plan!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: yes its a part of larger query, title does not have index. And when try with the **OFFSET** query first time it takes too much time for fetching.

Comment: @ChiragThakar: yes, used this on looping process, of course pass the parameter for `start_point and count`.

Comment: @RaJeshRiJo what do you mean *looping*? Looping in SQL will be slow no matter what you do - whether you use paging or a cursor. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? What is the *actual query* that is slow? Why are you looping at all instead of writing a single statement?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I dont use looping on SQL, i used looping on C# code and call the above req query inside that loop with parameters like `start_point and count` i needed.

Comment: Add the proper indexes. Nothing will improve performance if you don't - the query isn't the problem. The "delay" you experience is SQL Server sorting all the data the first time because there are no indexes. Solutions with `ROW_NUMBER` may result in the same delay for every row, if SQL Server has to recalculate the order. With the indexes, there may not be any noticable difference

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: thanks for ur valuable comments.:) let me try something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, will work for you.

```
SELECT ContentUrl FROM (
    select ContentUrl,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY title DESC) AS RowNumber  from EDContentMaster 
) AS InnerTable
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN @StartIndexParameter AND @StartIndexParameter + @Count
```

Comment: @RaJeshRiJo Checkout this answer.

Comment: How is this different than other answers using ROW_NUMBER?

Comment: @Chirag: It's bit more faster(almost 1/3 times faster). Thanks a lot.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i tried it according to my knowledge, and it works my friend. if with is not required then what is need to use that. 
Thank you!!

Comment: @ChiragThakar I didn't say that it doesn't work - it's essentially the same as the answer by Dhaval. Is there any difference in the execution plans?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sir, i think its faster in execution.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` in SQL Server versions 2005 to 2008 R2

```
with cte as 
(
    select row_number() over(order by title desc) as rno, 
           ContentUrl 
    from EDContentMaster
)
select * from cte where rno between 1001 and 1100
```

Comment: This is actually much slower that using OFFSET. It executes the same sorting AND has to calculate row_number

Comment: @Dhaval: this is slower than OFFSET, bcoz it took all records and fetch to cte first and then select particular 100 rows from cte.

Comment: Ok this is alternative of your Result.to make it faster first you have to check you Execution plan and check Title column require any Index..

Comment: @Dhaval: wat u said is right. I'm looking for a alternate one, bcoz OFFSET not working lower versions of SQL Server. But i wanted bit more faster option.

Comment: @RaJeshRiJo post the *actual* query and the limitations. If you say you tried `OFFSET` it implies you are targeting SQL 2012 and above. If you mention *looping*, you have other significant code that you haven't posted. Are you trying to emulate a cursor?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: acutally i tried this on my local machine, but in server i have 2008R2. later only understood OFFSET not working there. so i wanted a alternate and of course a faster one.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: i'm using 2005 so i cannot test it but what i've read so far is that `ROW_NUMBER` is _not_ much slower than `OFFSET`, if at all. Read [this](http://tinyurl.com/ost3hru) and [this](http://tinyurl.com/q6aanm5). It seems that `OFFSET` is also using a CTE  implicitely.  _"I actually asked some of the MS Sql folks at DevConnections end of March about performance of this feature vs. CTEs and they said it should perform exactly the same, that behind the scenes it is still creating a CTE."(comment in last link)_

Comment: @TimSchmelter execution plans display estimated costs, actual times [as shown here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2696/comparing-performance-for-different-sql-server-paging-methods/) show a difference in duration *and* IO, and much better performance in time to first page (FAST X hint used internally perhaps?). The important thing though is whether the optimizer will remember the sorted results from one call to the other, or have to recalculate them.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: performance tests that run milliseconds are not that meaningful. If i read the first comment in that link someone mentiones that on large tables with an index on the sort column a CTE + `ROW_NUMBER` is even faster than the `OFFSET`. However, if i had 2012 i would also use `OFFSET` since it's more readable and less work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use this?

```
SELECT ContentUrl from EDContentMaster LIMIT 100, 1001;
```

or

```
 SELECT ContentUrl from EDContentMaster LIMIT 100 OFFSET 10001;
```

Comment: Try this. I hope it will help now. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Comment: yup, i tried this already man, and i put the *query* on my question itself.